# ListPointPlot3D log scale axes?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I've been trying to get my y and z axes log-scaled on a 3D list Point Plot, for example (test data):

```
data={{.73,100,600},{.75,800,900},{.8,1100,2000},{.85,2100,4000},{.92,5000,9000},{1,10000,200000}};

ListPointPlot3D[data, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 1000
 ]
```

I have tried everything I could find in old posts, but everything seemed to be geared towards `Plot3D` - and doesn't seem to work for `ListPointPlot3D`.

Any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the option [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) for this purpose. For instance:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
    data,
    AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"},
    BaseStyle->{FontSize->20,FontFamily->"Times"},
    ScalingFunctions->{None,"Log","Log"},
    ImageSize->700
]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah - I tried this earlier but got the "unknown option name" error, so I assumed it wasn't compatible. If this works for you it must mean my version is too old I guess (I have 10.4?). :) Thanks! I'll look into updating.

Comment: @zack `ScalingFunctions` were only introduced in version 11.

Comment: Dang! Oh well :) Thanks!

Comment: I have Mathematica Version 11.1.1.0, but the `ScalingFunctions` option isn't recognized for ListPointPlot3D (for `Plot` it is). Is there any known workaround?